# Can quests disappear before I do them?

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm not sure but I think the quests, 'Path of the Hunter' and 'Wanted Dead' have disappeared before I did them. Because I remember seeing them on the map, but then I proceeded with the story, thinking that I will do them later. But now I don't see them.

I just finished "the man named Hoyt" mission, and so far I have only done one hunting quest, and there is no other. I have unlocked 6-7 radio towers. Or is it normal (i.e. will new hunting quests will appear as I progress?) but I'm 99% sure there were others before.

Comment: cant remember enough to direct you towards a proper solution, but I remember the secondary missions only showing up **if you are within proximity**. In the mean time I would suggest looking up a guide for these missions, just to point you towards the start of one you have not completed. They should all be within towns.

It is not normal for them to disappear; the hunting missions, for example, are required for end-tier upgrades.

Comment: @Timelord64 thanks. I thought the same and went to the towns and got near the bulletin boards. But they are not there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a player that has platinum on this game , even though I haven't played it in a while, I recall those hunting missions. You are right, as you progress they will unlock. I would suggest you leave all the side missions /hunting missions for last after you finish the story so you have something to do after the story is done. (they don't disappear, some you require some things to be able to unlock them.)

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the game, I realized that those missions were unlocked by liberating outposts. And I did one or two accidentally :) So I guess everything was normal.

However, I still suspect that there is some aspect of quests / activities that I do not understand, because in my second run, the knife throwing activity (at Amanaki Town) was unlocked at the very beginning of the game, however it was not unlocked in my first run. Is it because I never walked near that place?